# Python sending information to PHP

Tags: python, php, python-requests, scripting

I have this code:

`data.py`:

```
import requests
userdata = {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe", "password": "jdoe123"}
resp = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1/post.php', params=userdata)
print(resp.content)
```

`post.php`:

```
<?php 
$firstname = htmlspecialchars($_GET["firstname"]);
$lastname = htmlspecialchars($_GET["lastname"]);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_GET["password"]);
echo "firstname: $firstname lastname: $lastname password: $password";
?>
```

And in my localhost the page is seeing like this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\xampp\htdocs\post.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: lastname in C:\xampp\htdocs\post.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\post.php on line 4

firstname: lastname: password:
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Keen Lee.
It's an error, the website have to show me firstname: John, lastname: Doe, password: jdoe123
It only print it the echo without the variables

Comment: If i put POST in the PHP i have the same error: Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\xampp\htdocs\post.php on line 2 Notice: Undefined index: lastname in C:\xampp\htdocs\post.php on line 3 Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\post.php on line 4 firstname: lastname: password:

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `$_GET` with `$_POST`.

Comment: i have the same error:

Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\xampp\htdocs\post.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: lastname in C:\xampp\htdocs\post.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\post.php on line 4
firstname: lastname: password:

Comment: @OctavioBottari the parameters are posted from python, you can try the python script. when you visit the page directly,  no parameters were passed to PHP.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what you wrote. I thought that the parameters pass to php in the moment when i write resp = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1/post.php', params=userdata)